# phpThumb not working for large images on server

Tags: phpthumb

I have spent a lot time by searching and trying different options but with no luck :(
phpThumb is working like a charm on development machine but on server it fails with no error.I am using ajaxForm to upload image.

```
                $phpThumb->setSourceData($thumb_source_path);
                $phpThumb->setParameter('w', 180);
                $phpThumb->setParameter('h', 160);
                $phpThumb->setParameter('zc', true);
                $output_filename = $imgThumbPath;
                if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) { 

                    if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($output_filename))
                    {

                    }
                } else {

                    echo 'Failed:<pre>'.$phpThumb->fatalerror."\n\n".implode("\n\n", $phpThumb->debugmessages).'</pre>';
                }
```

[image: phpThumb.demo.check.php result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not getting error because of `@ImageCreateFromString($RawImageData);` After removing `@` I got to know that problem was related to `memory_limit`. My problem solved setting `memory_limit` to `-1` for infinite allocation.

Thanks